# How many different looking selections can be made?

Tags: combinatorics

Problem: Consider 12 balls (3 orange, 3 green, 3 blue, 3 red). We randomly choose 9 balls from the 12. How many different looking selections can be made?

I only know that ${12 \choose {3,3,3,3} }$ is the number of ways the 12 balls can be arranged with repetitive colours. But I don't know how to choose 9 balls out of 12 and then those 9 balls must be different looking.... What's the way to tackle this kind of problems? What concept is this problem related to?

Comment: If nothing else works, you can just bash it to death with some casework (which should not be too bad).

Comment: To save some work, look at the three balls left in the bag.  All three could be the same color, exactly two of them could be one color, or all three could be different colors.  In how many ways can each occur?